# How to auto shutdown my centOS7 desktop after downloading a file on chrome using command line command?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, shutdown

I would like to shutdown my CentOS7 desktop automatically 
after downloading a file(windows10 disc image) from chrome browser.

I would like to use the command on command line.

(Downloading windows10 disc images from Microsoft.com too slow.
I will take about 6 hours.)

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole task from command line:

```
$ wget DownloadURL && shutdown -h now
```

It will wait till download completion and shutdown PC after that. If you use `halt` instead of `shutdown` then you need to get a root shell.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Neo:

You could use the shutdown command for it:

```
shutdown -P +360
```

Where 360 are minutes. It makes a Shutdown scheduled.

Take care that the file is downloaded before this 360 minutes.

If you know the name of the file, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_to_check=/home/user/Downloads/example.txt

while [ ! -f "$file_to_check" ]
do
  sleep 5
done
shutdown -h now
```

And you can execute with:

```
/bin/bash pathToScript.sh &
```

It will check every 5 seconds if the file exist in a loop. If the file exist it will turn off the computer.

You can use a crontab too, but I think is enough with the above.

I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much!